# Is it good practice to save multiple Foreign Keys into CharField as a comma separated values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

just want to know whether its good to save multiple Foreign Keys into single Char field to avoid multiple DB calls to save and also maintain OnetoOne Relationship. Here is the situation.

**Person Model**

```
class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
   .....
   .....
   .....
```

**Secondary Degree Model**

```
class SecondaryDegree(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
```

**Person Secondary Degree With OnetoOne Relationship**

```
class PersonSecondaryDegree(models.Model):
   nomination_profile = models.OneToOneField('Person',null=False, blank=False)

   # Here i am using CharField instead of ForiegnKey.
   secondary_degree = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False) 

   is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=False,blank=False)
```

Comment: Why don't you put a `ForeignKey` to `SecondaryDegree` on the `Person`?

Comment: Because i have to maintain OneToOne relationship with nomination_profile. And Because of OneToOneField it won't allow duplicate value.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advice to use a `CharField` to store Foreign Key id's. It will prevent you from using standard SQL queries for simple operations, thus will prevent you from using the related features in the Django ORM.

It's usually best to give your database a logical structure and not make structure sacrifices for the performance. There are many other ways to improve performance, like indexing and caching. If you do it like that it will give you the most flexibility for the future.